# Hibernate is not setting foreign key in mysql even having the relation set in java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have the following configuration and code in my spring boot application but I am not getting a foreign key constraint in mysql can some one help please.

The Stock class:-

```
@Entity(name = "stock")
public class Stock {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "p_id")
    private String productId;

    @Column(name="p_desc")
    private String productDescription;

    @Column(name="p_quantity")
    private double productQuantityInStock;

    @Column(name = "p_threshold")
    private double productThresholdQuantity;

    @OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_productPrice"),referencedColumnName = "pr_id")
    private ProductPrice productPrice;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "listOfProducts")
    private Set<OrderList> orderLists;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public double getProductQuantityInStock() {
        return productQuantityInStock;
    }

    public void setProductQuantityInStock(double productQuantityInStock) {
        this.productQuantityInStock = productQuantityInStock;
    }

    public double getProductThresholdQuantity() {
        return productThresholdQuantity;
    }

    public void setProductThresholdQuantity(double productThresholdQuantity) {
        this.productThresholdQuantity = productThresholdQuantity;
    }

    public ProductPrice getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(ProductPrice productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }
}
```

Product Class :-

```
@Entity(name = "productprice")
public class ProductPrice {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "pr_id")
    private String PriceId;

    @Column(name="p_id")
    private String ProductId;

    @Column(name="price")
    private double Price;

    public String getPriceId() {
        return PriceId;
    }

    public void setPriceId(String priceId) {
        PriceId = priceId;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return ProductId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        ProductId = productId;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

Project.properties

[image]

Application log for Constraints

[image]

Mysql DDL

[image]

If you can see the mysql ddl there is no foreign key constraint. I have tried this with all possible combinations in JoinColumn and I could not see Foreign key. And I came to know that just `KEY` means index in mysql. Which I am not expecting. Any help or material or directions will help. Thanks

Comment: I ran the exact same Entities and it created stock table with Foreign key. Only difference for me was that I removed the referencedColumnName. May be there is difference in the Hibernate version.

Comment: for better understanding [check this](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: @NickDiv can you please let me know the version that you have used. I am using 5.3.1 Final

Comment: @venkatReddi I am using 4.3.11.Final but before changing the version can you try removing referencedColumnName from the annotation

Comment: @NickDiv sure will do that. Thank you

Comment: That without having referencedColumnName surprisingly worked.Is it because I am using Spring-Data-Jpa? Any idea. That would help me understand this behavior